# Extracting data from MongoDB in R to create vectors

Tags: r, mongodb, vector, gps, mongolite

I am using a "mongolite" library to connect R with Mongo db. Below mentioned is the data from the collection. I want to store all "Lat", "Long" and "Time" values separately in the form of vectors in R. Can you please tell me how it is possible?

```
  > con$find()
                 Nom            Time      Lat       Long
  1            Cap1 2017-05-18 14:22:01 47.29393  5.010343
  2            Cap1 2017-05-18 14:22:02 47.29394  5.010370
  3            Cap1 2017-05-18 14:22:00 47.29391  5.010314
  4            Cap1 2017-05-18 14:21:59 47.29389  5.010288
  5            Cap1 2017-05-18 14:22:03 47.29395  5.010395
```

Comment: it appears to return a data frame. `d <- con$find()` then `d$Lat` and `d$Long` does not work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.